# Trace of a square root of two matrices

Tags: radicals, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices, trace, positive-semidefinite

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two real symmetric PSD matrices and they commute. Simplify: $\big(\text{tr}(\sqrt{AB})\big)^{2}$. I know that $\text{tr}(AB)\ne \text{tr}(A)\text{tr}(B)$.

Note that the matrix $B$ might be singular. Hence, the square root of a singular matrix might not be defined. How can I proceed?

Comment: Practically speaking, you will compute the eigenvalues of $AB$ (or equivalently, $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$, which are guaranteed to be non-negative and real), and then your expression is equal to the square of the sum of the square-roots of those eigenvalues. I'm not sure there's much you can simplify.